# How programatically replace image with selected image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uitableview

Am new in iOS Development.

I want to replace image with selected image .

I used following code .

```
-(void)imageTappedWithTag:(int)tag andType:(NSString *)type
{
    NSLog(@"%@  %d",type,tag);
    NSLog(@"test%@",[[ownerSwaps.imgArray objectAtIndex:tag]valueForKey:@"swap_image_thumb"]);

        NSURL *url=nil;
    NSString *urlStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[UIImage imageNamed:[[ownerSwaps.imgArray objectAtIndex:tag]valueForKey:@"swap_image_thumb"]]];

    urlStr=[urlStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
    NSString* urlTextEscaped = [urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlTextEscaped];
    SwapDetailImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"fbicon.png"];
    [SwapDetailImg setAlpha:0.2];
    [self downloadImageWithURL:url completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSData *data) {
        if (succeeded)
        {
            SwapDetailImg.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
            [SwapDetailImg setAlpha:1.0];
        }
    }];



}
```

I have a  horizontal `ScrollView` on `UITableViewCell` row .when I click on scroll view,then the image gets replaced with my header image.

please help out how i can replace this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem at the first look, is at the link. You are passing an `UIImage` instance to `NSString *urlStr`. Try changing your your `urlStr` to:

```
NSString *urlStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[ownerSwaps.imgArray objectAtIndex:tag]valueForKey:@"swap_image_thumb"] ];
```